# How to display relationship with back reference at django template through User?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have such models

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    """Employee information."""
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='employee', unique=True)
    position = models.CharField("current position in a company", max_length=64, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField("date of birth", null=True)
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(
        Technology, through="Skill", verbose_name="skills", blank=True)


class Technology(models.Model):
    """Technologies."""
    name = models.CharField('technology name', max_length=32, unique=True)

class Skill(models.Model):
    """Information about an employee's skills."""
    LEVELS = (
        ('basic', 'Basic'),
        ('intermediate', 'Intermediate'),
        ('advanced', 'Advanced'),
        ('expert', 'Expert'),
    )
    employee = models.ForeignKey(
        Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="employee_skills")
    technology = models.ForeignKey(Technology, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateField(
        verbose_name='Works with since:')
    level = models.CharField("level", max_length=64, choices=LEVELS)
```

And I can't understand why my template code doesn't work

**template.html**

```
{{ user.employee.position }}
{{ user.employee.birth_date }}
{{ user.employee.summary }}

{% for i in  user.employee.skills.all %}
{{ i.technology.name }}
{{ i.level }}
{% endfor %}
```

I can't see absolutely nothing. All models possible to see at adminpanel. And else then I using TemplateView such as

```
class AccountView(TemplateView):

    template_name = "profile.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AccountView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)      
        context['skills'] = 
        Skill.objects.filter(employee__user=self.request.user)

        return context
```

then everything works fine.

Comment: It should be `{% for i in skills %}`, since that is the name with which you bound the skills.

Comment: a user is associated with many employees, which skills are you referring to?

Comment: @Sayse One User -> One Employee

Comment: Have you tried with `{% for i in  user.employee.employee_skills.all %}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something wrong with the modeling. You should use a `OneToOneField` between `Employee` and `User`. In essence an `OneToOneField` is a *unique* `ForeignKey`. It will however change some logic, such that `user.employee` will access the related `Employee` object, not a `QuerySet` of `Employee`s:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    # ...
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='employee'
    )
    # ...
```

In your `AccountView`, you unified `'skills'` with the skills of that employee, indeed:

```
class AccountView(TemplateView):

    template_name = "profile.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AccountView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)      
        context.update(
            skills=Skill.objects.filter(employee__user=self.request.user).select_related('technology')
        )
        return context
```

You might want to use `.select_related(..)` here to prevent the so-called "*N+1 problem*" where *for each* skill, you will make an extra query.

So you can render the skills with:

```
{% for skill in skills %}
    {{ skill.technology.name }}
    {{ skill.level }}
{% endfor %}
```

or you can access is through:

```
{% for skill in request.user.employee.employee_skills.all %}
    {{ skill.technology.name }}
    {{ skill.level }}
{% endfor %}
```

although the above is less safe, since it is possible that a `User` has no related `Employee` object.

Comment: your code working with using TemplateView, but doesnt't work with user.  You are slightly wrong using `i` instesd `skill`, but that's not the point. I think what  `{% for skill in user.employee.skills %}` wrong construction/

Comment: @Jekson: what if you use `request.user` instead?

Comment: Willem, I got   `'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable`

Comment: @jekson: ah yes, you need to add `.all` as well. Sorry :s.

Comment: Hm nothing displaying

Comment: @Jekson: hold on, that's the `through` relation? Then it is `request.user.employee.employee_skills.all`. By using `skills` itself, you will get `technology` objects.

Answer (score 2):

Your Employee model currently has a one to many relationship with a user

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    """Employee information."""
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='employee', unique=True)
```

according to your comment you need a one to one relation ship so you need to change this to use a [`OneToOneField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield) instead of a `ForeignKey`

> Conceptually, this is similar to a ForeignKey with unique=True, but the “reverse” side of the relation will directly return a single object.

Comment: @Jekson - It wouldn't have worked if you'd tried to look from the "reverse" side as the docs show, you've specified that the key is unique to a user but django will still treat it as any other foreign key and return a query set instead of the single object